# How to run background location task in Expo React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, location, background-task

Im trying to create a background task, mainly for android, which permit me get the current location of the user every x seconds and send it by a socket to a server socket. I read the documentation from Expo and tried with Expo Location startLocationUpdatesAsync() method. Apparently this functionality requires have Expo TaskManager installed and define the task. This actually works and gives me the location:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task';

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }) => {
    console.log("Task executed");
    try {
        if (error) {
          // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
          return;
        }
        if (data) {
          const { locations } = data;
          console.log("paso");
          setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("paso timeout");
          }, 5000);
          setInterval(() => {
              console.log(locations[0]);
          }, 4000);
          // do something with the locations captured in the background
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});

const requestPermissions = async () => {
    try {
        const { status: foregroundStatus } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (foregroundStatus === 'granted') {
            const { status: backgroundStatus } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (backgroundStatus === 'granted') {
                if (await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME)) {
                  await Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME);
                  console.log("stop");
              }
              await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
                  accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
              });
              console.log("start");
          }
        }   
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`requestPermissions: ${error}`);
    }
};

const PermissionsButton = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Button onPress={requestPermissions} title="Enable background location" />
  </View>
);
```

Logs from the console (manually change the lat and lng to 0 for no dox):

- LOG  stop
- LOG  start
- LOG  Task executed
- LOG  paso
- LOG  {"coords": {"accuracy": 11.392000198364258, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0.5, "heading": 0, "latitude": 0, "longitude": 0, "speed": 0}, "timestamp": 1696817481586}
- LOG  paso timeout

The problem here is the task runs once, also if i leave the app in background fast enough the setTimeout and setInterval dont run until i open the app.

So i noticed that exists another package that uses TaskManager. The Expo BackgroundFetch. I also tried combining with this expo package and now the task runs every minute, but doesnt get the location:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = 'background-fetch-with-location';

TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async ({ data, error }) => {
  const now = Date.now();
  console.log(`Got background fetch call at date: ${new Date(now).toISOString()}`);
  try {
    if (error) {
      return;
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log("paso if(data)");
      console.log(data);
      const { locations } = data;
      console.log(locations);
      const location = locations[0];
      console.log(location);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
  return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;
});

async function registerBackgroundFetchAsync() {
  return await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
    minimumInterval: 5, // 15 minutes
    stopOnTerminate: false, // android only,
    startOnBoot: true, // android only
  });
}

async function unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync() {
  return await BackgroundFetch.unregisterTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
}

export default function AppJS() {
  const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = React.useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    checkStatusAsync();
  }, []);

  const checkStatusAsync = async () => {
    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    const isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
    setStatus(status);
    setIsRegistered(isRegistered);
  };

  const toggleFetchTask = async () => {
    if (isRegistered) {
      if (await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK)) {
        await Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
      }
      await unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync();
    } else {
      if (!(await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK))) {
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        });
      }
      await registerBackgroundFetchAsync();
    }

    checkStatusAsync();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text>
          Background fetch status:{' '}
          <Text style={styles.boldText}>
            {status && BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus[status]}
          </Text>
        </Text>
        <Text>
          Background fetch task name:{' '}
          <Text style={styles.boldText}>
            {isRegistered ? BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK : 'Not registered yet!'}
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}></View>
      <Button
        title={isRegistered ? 'Unregister BackgroundFetch task' : 'Register BackgroundFetch task'}
        onPress={toggleFetchTask}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Logs from the console:

- LOG  Got background fetch call at date: 2023-10-09T02:05:04.771Z
- LOG  paso if(data)
- LOG  {}
- LOG  undefined
- LOG  [TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object]

**What am i doing wrong? Is there a way to get the current location from the user every 10s approximately in background?**

I tried to create a background task that process (send to a server by sockets) current location every x seconds, but i only get closer to this two results: getting the current location once when the app is in background and, in the other hand, running every minute the task in background without the current location.

Comment: I'm a little confused, where in your code do you make the request itself to the backend?

Comment: @MikeK . The code isn't the final code, it's just an example code which I copied from the expo documentation and made some changes to test it. My problem was bakground tasks didn't worked. In my real code I use a socket instance within the background task code and emit an event to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the background task executed from startLocationUpdatesAsync using only the expo-location and expo-task-manager doesnt work in Expo Go, but does when you build the app. I looked for an answer for days, i read the expo documentation (where it should be this explanation), researched a lot and finally i found [this issue from expo github](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22183#issuecomment-1561762032) that helped me to realize what was wrong.

Hope this helps to another person like me (literally i was looking for a solution for days).